chrome.debugger.attach() not attaching to the current tab
I am trying to attach a debugger to the current tab but it gives me this error
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension

Here is my background script file that is handling this
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (req, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (req.name == "test") {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true
    })

    console.log(tab)
    const tabId = tab.id
    console.log(tabId)
    const text = "Hello there mate"

    await chrome.debugger.detach({ tabId: tabId })
    console.log("before attach")
    await chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId }, "1.2")
    console.log("after attach")

    await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Runtime.enable")
    await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "DOM.enable")

    for (const char of text) {
      console.log(char)
      await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", {
        type: "keyDown",
        text: char
      })
      await sleep(50)
      await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", {
        type: "keyUp",
        text: char
      })
      await sleep(50)
    }
    sendResponse(tabId)
  }
})


I am sending the a message from my content script 5 seconds after the content script loads.
Why is this not working ?
I was expecting it to attach the debugger and run the dispatch event in order to write in a input field.

The error means you're attaching to a chrome-extension:// tab of a different extension or to a normal tab that contains an iframe of a different extension.

The tab case is solved by removing chrome.tabs.query and using sender.tab.id instead.

The iframe case is a bug in Chrome and the workaround is to remove all such iframes from the tab in your content script. There's no 100% reliable method of finding them, but in most cases it's sufficient to check the src attribute:
if (window.length) for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(
  `iframe[src^="chrome-extension://"]:not([src^="${chrome.runtime.getURL('')}"])`))
    el.remove();

Some extensions add their frames inside a closed Shadow DOM, though, so in that case you'll need to check all elements in the document:
(function removeExtensionFrames(root) {
  if (root || window.length)
    for (const el of (root || document).querySelectorAll(
    `iframe[src^="chrome-extension:"]:not([src^="${chrome.runtime.getURL('')}"])`))
      el.remove();
  for (let el of root.querySelectorAll('*'))
    if (!el.shadowRoot && (el = chrome.dom.openOrClosedShadowRoot(el)))
      removeExtensionFrames(el);
})();

You may want to store the elements somewhere to re-add them afterwards.


P.S. Either patch your onMessage listener or don't use async, more info.

Thanks a lot, it seems like I had an iframe of another extension in my browser. I removed that  and it worked. Also I will make it so that my extension automatically disables the other extension temporarily using the "management" permission.
And if it is a bug, where can we report it ? Or is it already reported ?

And what do you think about the approach of using the debugger API to write on input fields. The normal input field worked without the debugger approach but, in X (previously twitter) the input section is not a ordinary input section , it is a div with complex mechanism. When I use the dispatchEvent(keyborad event , input event) approach it does not. But thankfully this debugger approach worked. But do you think there are other alternatives ?


There's a link to the bug in the answer. 2) There are no universally reliable alternatives, but it's usually possible to dispatch the events used by the site, which you can see by inspecting its code in devtools. There's also document.execCommand, example.


How can I view what event the particular div is listening to in devtools ?
And isn't the document.execCommand deprecated ?


You can do it in devtools, it has a panel for event listeners. 2) It still works and will likely work for the foreseeable future because there's no alternative in the web platform.


Hello @woxxom !
Do you have any suggestion on, how can I deal with loading state in a browser extension  ? Like waiting till the network becomes idle just like puppeteer's await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
or
await page.waitForNetworkIdle()

`
await new Promise((resolve) => {
const listener = async (
tabId: number,
changeInfo: chrome.tabs.TabChangeInfo
) => {
if (tabId === updatedTab.id && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
const tab = await chrome.tabs.get(tabId)
console.log(tab)
console.log(updatedTab)
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener) // Remove listener once page is loaded
resolve()
}
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener)
})
`
I am currently using this approach.

But this is not working as most sites now a days, are streamed in. So the status is completed even tho we are still loading. Is there any good solution to this ?
